# Определить одинаковые элементы в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно при переборе массива выполнить условие в зависимости от того есть элемент в массиве или нет.

```
foreach ($arr as $items) {
    // Здесь, если первый элемент массива со значением name,
    // то выполнить одно условие, если это второй элемент
    // со значением name то выполнить другое условие.
 }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией array_search она вернет индекс в массиве или null. Ну а дальше проверяем на null и выполняем условие в зависимости от возвращенного значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь все зависит от того, какого объема этот массив, и что нужно делать с элементами, которые повторяются.

Я бы предложил сделать так: пройти все элементы массива и построить массив, где ключами будут значения, значения будут - ключи первоначального массива:

```
$array = [...]; //это общий массив с исходными данными
$arraySpecial = []; //это будет как раз учетный массив
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $arraySpecial[$value][] = $key;
    unset($array[$key]); //чтобы не дублировать данные, можно удалить их, все равно ключи (т.е. значения массива с исходными данными) все равно будут идти в нужном порядке
}
```

Собственно все, теперь у вас есть массив $arraySpecial в котором содержится вся статистика по вашему изначальному массиву.

Пример выполнения:

```
$array = ['as'=>1, 'sd'=>0, 'wer'=>1, 'were'=>4, 'dfg'=>1, 'cvb'=>3, 'rte'=>0, 'cvb'=>2];
$arraySpecial = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $arraySpecial[$value][] = $key;
    unset($array[$key]);
}
print_r($arraySpecial);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => as
            [1] => wer
            [2] => dfg
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => sd
            [1] => rte
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => were
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => cvb
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

для начала можете использовать расширенную конструкцию foreach:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    // все остальное
}
```